# How do I flash modified firmware to ATtiny85-based USB device from a mac?

Tags: firmware

I recently purchased a "BrushKnob" - custom USB controller for photoshop. The device is based on the AVR ATtiny85 chip, plugs in via USB,and has 4 output signals that mimic the following 4 US keyboard keys: []eb

The firmware code is open on GitHub (link below) and the programmer says one can modify the keys via the code. My question is after I've made the changes to the code, how to I flash the new firmware to the device from my mac?

More info on the device: https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/brushknob-speed-up-your-creation-workflow-painting-art#/comments

Github code:https://github.com/kmwtr/BrushKnob